# Add action on fragment before exit the App

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

I have a small problem of coding.

My goal: I have 2 fragment [0] and [1]. My default fragment is [0]. Once on [1] I press the return key and I return to the fragment [0] (instead of closing the application).

Here is a code that works correctly,

knowing that the fragment [1] is already on the stack:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new FragmentUn().addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

and here is the code on the backPressed:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    } else if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

This code works very well but what I want to do is to add an action (popUp) once to arrive on the fragment [0] which asks the user if he wants to leave the application or not when one presses the return key (here the app simply closes)

To do this, I wrote:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        } else if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        } else {
            AlertDialog.Builder exitPopUp = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            exitPopUp.setTitle("Exit");
            exitPopUp.setMessage("Voulez-vous quitter L'App ?");
            exitPopUp.setPositiveButton("Oui", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
            exitPopUp.setNegativeButton("Non", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                }
            });
            exitPopUp.setNeutralButton("Noter", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
                    Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                    // To count with Play market backstack, After pressing back button,
                    // to taken back to our application, we need to add following flags to intent.
                    goToMarket.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY |
                            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT |
                            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
                    try {
                        startActivity(goToMarket);
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName())));
                    }
                }
            });

            exitPopUp.show();
        }
}
```

Result ==> The app immediately displays the popUp when you press return on either fragment [0] or [1]. Except what I wish is only to arrive on fragment [0] that popUp is displayed. [1] - return key -> [0] - return key -> Exit popUp.

So what must I do to make it work properly? Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            super.onBackPressed();
            MainFragment main = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("main");
            if (main != null && main.isVisible()) {
                if (mExitCheck < 1) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Press back again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    //mExitCheck = 0 is an int
                    mExitCheck = 0;

                    //Finish() to exit the app
                    finish();
                }
                mExitCheck++;
            } else {
                showMain();
            }
        }
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. Sorry but I am a little lost in your code. I can do anything on mExitCheck i have the error: cannot resolve symbol and on showMain(): cannot resolve method. Can you please inject (edit) it on mine, if i want to show the popUp on the fragment [0] ?

Comment: Check out the new answer

Answer (score 0):

easiest thing to do is set an int to 0(OR any flag that lets you know you are on the first fragment) something like this.

```
    //do this for your first fragment
    Fragment fragment = MainFragment.newInstance();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = 
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.layout_container, fragment, "main").commit();
    mCurrentFrag = 0;

    // and this for others
    Fragment fragment = MainFragment.newInstance();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = 
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.layout_container, fragment, "main").commit();
    mCurrentFrag = 1;
```

then do the following

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mCurrentFrag == MAIN_FRAG){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                AlertDialog.Builder exitPopUp = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                exitPopUp.setTitle("Exit");
                exitPopUp.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?");
                exitPopUp.setPositiveButton("Oui", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });
                exitPopUp.setNegativeButton("Non", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    }
                });
                exitPopUp.setNeutralButton("Noter", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
                        Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                        goToMarket.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY |
                                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT |
                                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
                        try {
                            startActivity(goToMarket);
                        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                    Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName())));
                        }
                    }
                });

                exitPopUp.show();
            }
        });
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```